# Show multiple joined rows

Tags: mysql, join, php, relations

I have a simple relational MySQL database with users, cars an a log table. Everything works fine. In the log table I want to 'register' the users of a car. But a car can have two users at the same time.

My question: How can I show multiple users in the log table, using the relational database?

My database structure:

Table `users`

```
user_id  name   phone
-------  -----  -----
1        john   123
2        kevin  456
```

---

Table `cars`

```
car_id  nr   brand
------  ---  -----
1       666  Ford
2       999  Dodge
```

---

Table `log`

```
log_id  car_id  user_id1  user_id2
------  ------  --------  --------
1       1       1         2
```

---

The `car.car_id` is related to `log.car_id` and `users.user_id` is related to `log.user_id1` and `log.user_id2`.

Supposed SQL:

```
SELECT log.*, cars.*, users.*
FROM log
LEFT JOIN cars ON log.car_id=car.car_id
LEFT JOIN users ON log.user_id1=users.user_id
LEFT JOIN users ON log.user_id2=users.user_id
```

PHP (in loop of course):

```
echo $row["brand"];
echo $row["name"]; // user_id1
echo $row["name"]; // user_id2
```

It's working for only one name. How to show the names of `user_id1` and `user_id2` in the same "log" row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using aliases like this:

```
SELECT l.*, c.*, u1.*, u2.*
FROM log l
LEFT JOIN cars c ON l.car_id=c.car_id
LEFT JOIN users u1 ON l.user_id1=u1.user_id
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON l.user_id2=u2.user_id
```

(Note that it's bad practice to use "SELECT *" except for ad-hoc queries. So you should instead enumerate the exact columns you want to select.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how does the output look like? I've tried things like 'echo $row['u1.name'], but that's not working..

Comment: @Niles I suspect you need to use column aliases for the u1 and u2 columns so that PHP can distinguish between them. E.g. `SELECT l...., c..., u1.user_id "u1user_id", u1.name "u1name", u1.phone "u1phone",  u2.user_id "u2user_id", u2.name "u2name", u2.phone "u2phone" FROM log l .....`  You can then hopefully refer to these aliases from PHP.